# indecomposable module over a local ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

As we all know, for an arbitrary ring, any finite length module is indecomposable iff the endomorphism ring is local.

I have a question:

> If $R$ is local ring, $M\in R-\mathrm{Mod}$, is $M$ indecomposable iff $\mathrm{End}(M)$ is local?

Of course, if End(M) is local, then we have M is indecomposable. For the converse is there a counterexample？Especially in commutative Noetherian local rings.

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If $R$ is local, but not noetherian, the answer is negative.

Comment: @user26857 can you give the counterexample here?thanks

Comment: I'm waiting for an answer when $R$ is noetherian, since the answer in this case is also negative the example I know becomes irrelevant for your question.

Comment: @user26857 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288655/indecomposable-module-over-a-local-ring